# Is Escaping multiple characters in lucene possible?

Tags: lucene, escaping, kibana

I have a lot of lucene queries that contains a lot of characters with special meaning like colons, slashes, quotation marks, etc.
I am aware that it is possible to escape single character by using  '\', but is it possible to enclose whole sentence into something to be matched exactly in a query, without any of the symbols being interpreted?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your analyzer removing any non-letter symbol?

Comment: Actually, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [QueryParser.escape](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape-java.lang.String-) escapes everything in the string passed in to it.

Also, using phrase queries generally makes most query syntax irrelevant (`myfield:"I +do +not have:to /worry/ about^22 -query -syntax here~2"`), with the exception of quotes. If a phrase is what you are attempting to search, that is.

Comment: I am searching for generic parts of a dictionary, so quotes are common as keys are usually strings. `QueryParser.escape` seems to somewhat work, but it does not escape colons. To be more specific I am looking for something that would allow to do something like regex, or nested lookup in a json \ python dict type of reports, if it is even possible via kibana's web interface.

Comment: @PapeK24 - QueryParser.escape does indeed escape colons, just ran "this:that" through it, and it returned "this\:that", so it certainly appears to be working correctly. Don't really follow what you are trying to do, but if you are saying you want parse a json into fields and values to search, you would need to use a json parser for that.

Comment: Basically I wonder if I can make query from web logz.io's kibana's search bar like *id: 123* AND *status: 2* anywhere in the message with nothing but wildcards interpreted.